# How to disable/enable the touchpad for the Lenovo Yoga 900 13ISK2

Tags: linux, touchpad

**Solved (2016-11-15)**:  See more below the question.

## Detailled description of the problem

I'm trying to get the touchpad disabled when I press the Fn+F6 key
(actually I don't have to press the Fn key bacause of my BIOS setup)
on my Lenovo Yoga 900-13ISK2.

Before trying anything whenever I pressed the Fn+F6 key I got the
following in the `dmesg`:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xbf on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e03f <keycode>' to make it known.
atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xbf on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e03f <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Also whenever I put the laptop in "tablet mode", I could see the
following in the dmesg:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xbf on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e03f <keycode>' to make it known.
ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xbf on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e03f <keycode>' to make it known.
```

So it seems that when put into tablet mode it's like
pressing/releasing the Fn+F6 key along with another event.  That last
event seems to be related with the keyboard's backlight (since
pressing Fn+Space to control the backlight induces the same logs in
the `dmesg`).  When coming out of tablet mode to laptop mode, only the
`ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1` gets logged.

All this happens using Linux 4.8.  I used the Ubuntu's
`config-4.4.0-43-generic` as the base for creating the `.config` file
(shown in https://gist.github.com/mvaled/36b2aa23b194d33ecd5e43efe8905cba).

Afterwards, I created `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-yoga.hwdb`:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*80UE*:pvr*YOGA*900-13ISK2*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_bf=touchpad_toggle
```

After `udevadm hwdb -u` and `udevadm trigger` (or reboot), pressing
the Fn+F6 stops logging the unknown key events and `evtest` shows the
key:

```
Event: type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value bf
Event: type 1 (EV_KEY), code 530 (KEY_TOUCHPAD_TOGGLE), value 0
```

But the touchpad remains enabled.

I've been able to disable/enable the touchpad by issuing:

```
$ xinput set-prop "SYNA2B29:00 06CB:77C6" 'Device Enabled' 0
$ xinput set-prop "SYNA2B29:00 06CB:77C6" 'Device Enabled' 1
```

At this point I'm stuck.  Which component should capture the
KEY_TOUCHPAD_TOGGLE event and do something about it?

I know that touchpad is being driven by the 'i2c_designware_platform' driver.
The keyboard seems to be driven by 'ideapad_laptop'.  Is that reasonable?

## Solution

The solution is to change the file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-yoga.hwdb` to:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*80UE*:pvr*YOGA*900-13ISK2*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_bf=f21
```

@dirkt provided information about the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`.  Reading this file is clear the X11 maps the key F21 to XF86TouchpadToggle:

```
key <FK21>   {      [ XF86TouchpadToggle    ]       };
```

So instead of mapping the scancode to `touchpad_toggle` I just map it to function key F21.

No scripts needed.

#### Remaining issues

This laptop sends this event when you put it tablet mode.  But when coming back to laptop mode it does not send it again so the touchpad remains disabled.

Furthermore, if you disable the touchpad while in laptop mode, going to tablet mode enables it.

Comment: Hi @MateuszPiotrowski, I edited the confirmed answer to include the solution.  I hope it pass the peer review.

Comment: You could as well just paste it as a new answer :)

Comment: Ha, they almost rejected your edit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/190563. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved all the difficult parts of the puzzle :-)

You either need to run a dedicated program that reacts on the toggle command, or use an existing program that is running anyway and can react on keys. Some window managers can be very flexibly configured to react on keys, for example I'm using `fvwm` for the brightness and volume keys on my laptop. So find out what window manager you are using, and how you can configure it.

You can find out the X keycode instead of the kernel keycode by running `xev`, focusing it and pressing Fn+F6.

The second problem is that to perform a toggle operation, you need to know the current state. The simplest way is probably to write a little shell script to read the `Device Enabled` property with `xinput`, and then either enable or disable it with `xinput set-prop`. Run this shell script from your window manager (if you can) whenever you receive the X even code you found out.

## Solution

The solution is to change the file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-yoga.hwdb` to:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*80UE*:pvr*YOGA*900-13ISK2*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_bf=f21
```

@dirkt provided information about the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`.  Reading this file is clear the X11 maps the key F21 to XF86TouchpadToggle:

```
key <FK21>   {      [ XF86TouchpadToggle    ]       };
```

So instead of mapping the scancode to `touchpad_toggle` I just map it to function key F21.

No scripts needed.

#### Remaining issues

This laptop sends this event when you put it tablet mode.  But when coming back to laptop mode it does not send it again so the touchpad remains disabled.

Furthermore, if you disable the touchpad while in laptop mode, going to tablet mode enables it.

Comment: On a terminal over X, `evtest` do capture the events.  But `xev` logs nothing.  Trying to create a custom shortcut using Ubuntu's Unity settings, does not see the key press either.

So, there should be some component (probably in the X stack) that is dismissing the key.

Comment: That's strange, the X keysym `XF86XK_TouchpadToggle` exists, and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` seems to contain a translation in the `evdev` section. And I do know that e.g. the volume and brightness keys in the same section work properly. I'm not familiar enough with X keyboard stuff to give advice how to debug this. In principle, you should be able to define your own keyboard translation in case there's a bug in the default one.

Comment: Thanks!  I think you've got some point there.  The section 'evdev' translate the key F21 to that.  From my previous research it seems that Linux used to use F21 for the touchpad toggle.  Now I just have to learn how to extend that mapping.

Comment: I just changed the hwdb file to send the F21 instead of th touchpad_toggle and now the X11 properly enable/disabled the touchpad.  And, of course, it works when I put the laptop in tablet mode.  Unfortunally when I come out of tablet mode back to laptop mode, the event is not send and I have to enable the touchpad manually.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using synaptics under xorg, I often use :

```
 synclient touchpadoff=1 # for disable and =0 for enable
```